# Calling C++ member functions with the thiscall convention

Tags: c++, delphi, segmentation-fault, calling-convention, member-functions

I have an application written in C++ that loads my DLL that is written in Delphi. The application calls an exported function of the DLL and passes it a pointer to an object of a class that has several member functions that I want to call from my Delphi DLL. I have written a Delphi class equivalent of the C++ class:

```
CClass = class
    procedure A(param : Integer); virtual; abstract;
    procedure B; virtual; abstract;
end
```

and the C++ class looks the same

```
class CClass {
public:
    virtual void A(int) = 0;
    virtual void B() = 0;
};
```

The member functions use the thiscall calling convention which does not have a Delphi equivalent. This probably means I need to use assembly. I have tried:

```
function exported_procedure(ptr : CClass) : Integer; cdecl;
begin
    asm
        push ebx;
        push esi;
        mov ecx, ptr;
        push 4;
        call CClass.A;
        pop esi;
        pop ebx;
    end;

    Result := 0;
end
```

But I get a segmentation fault when the application calls this function. How do I properly call the member function?

Comment: How are you newing up the class? Which C++ compiler compiled the C++ bits?

Comment: @Billy Visual Studio (probably 2008) compiled the C++ code, and it passes a pointer to a dynamically allocated instance of a derived class to the exported procedure.

Comment: @John: Yes, but it's a virtual function. The vtbl structure needs to be populated -- and that needs to be done from C++. You're probably better off exposing a C interface that's easier for Delphi to call rather than attempting to hack around vc+.

Comment: +1 Calling a Visual Studio C++ class from Delphi isn't going to work out. Try a C interface or COM.

Comment: @Billy: Is there a way I can do this from delphi if I have all the vtable offsets?

Comment: @David, COM interfaces in C++ are nothing more than abstract classes. There's nothing wrong with calling a C++ class from Delphi. Anyone using COM does it every day, whether knowingly or not.

Comment: @Billy, the vtbl structure *is* populated. The C++ code populated it when it instantiated `CClass`. It passed a pointer when it called the Delphi function, so `ptr` is a pointer to the vtbl member of the class. Add zero to the address stored in that field, dereference it, and you have the address to jump to to call `A`. (Add four instead of zero, and you have the address for `B` instead. Better to use `vmtoffset`, though.)

Comment: @Rob still getting an access violation, the program is dereferencing 0, which is probably because of a bad this pointer. Can you take a look really fast? http://pastebin.com/kVvULDCb

Comment: I don't know, John. It looks OK to me. Use the debugger to examine the stack and the rest of memory. Step through the code to see which memory-dereference is invalid. (You don't need to save or restore EBX and ESI since you don't use them, but that shouldn't have any bearing on the problem.)

Comment: @Rob: The OP has not posted the code indicating where he created the actual instance. If he's trying to create the class in Delphi and then pass it to C++, that would result in failures.

Comment: @Rob and Billy: I actually did indicate where the instance is created in one of my comments above: "Visual studio ... compiled the C++ code, and it passes a pointer to a dynamically allocated instance of a derived class to the exported procedure." Also, I figured out the problem: vmtoffset was calculating the offset to be one more than it should have. The offset should have been 18, not 1C. I guess I'll have to subtract 4 from vmtoffset to get the real offset. Can you think of a way where I won't have to write this assembly for every member in the class? And thanks Rob for helping so much.

Comment: The VMT offset is wrong? Hmm. Perhaps the C++ class has a virtual destructor occupying the first vtbl. The offset of `A` in the code here should be 0. To avoid having to write special code for each function, you can try adapting [the code I wrote for Microsoft's windowless RTF control](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/windowless-rtf). It generates a stub for each method. On the Delphi side, the methods are all stdcall, but the stub massages the parameters to turn it into thiscall. Loop in *TOM.pas*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asm looks fine, that's how we call a thiscall interface. But this is a class. I don't think there's any reason to assume CClass.A actually calls void A(int). You'd have to figure out the correct offset. Having a Delphi class won't help I think: you should find out the offsets in C++, add that offset to ptr and call that address.

Comment: Can you look at this: http://pastebin.com/QVf7Q1HQ If I examine the ecx register after doing the push dword offset ss:[ecx] line, ollydbg says that it's a pointer to somewhere within the module that called my DLL, which is good. However, I'm still getting a segfault. Note that this function in the pastebin is a different one that takes a const char* as an argument.

Comment: Use the `vmtoffset` operator in the assembler to programmatically determine the position of `A` in the VMT: `mov eax, [ecx]; call [eax + vmtoffset CClass.A]`

Comment: @Rob: Thanks, that's very much more convenient.